# NSURL in memory RAM

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, nsurl, ram

Is it possible to use an NSURL to reference a file in RAM... I'm not meaning longer term memory ~16 GB storage, but dedicated RAM ~512MB?

I saw the following site, but it seems to address it from a different angle..
http://memfrag.se/blog/Memory-Mapped-Files

Comment: Do you want to have a file in memory or do you want a `NSURL` to reference a memory block?

Comment: @JustSid

Hi JustSid  
Thanks for your question.  
Does it make a difference to most iOS SDK's if the underlying NSURL is a memory block or a file? Is there an advantage to one or the other?

Comment: Yes, there is a huge difference but if you have to ask then you probably don't want to use memory mapped files at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can have that. URL works as **Universal** resource locator.

You can define a scheme, e.g. `memory://MEMORY_ADRESS` for a file in memory.

Also, if you want to use a `NSURLRequest` with memory mapped files (whatever the request should do), you can register a `NSURLProtocol` instance for this scheme.

You can also subclass `NSFileManager` adding the ability to understand `memory://` URLs.

Comment: So then, is the address to look like this:  memory://0xFFFFFFFF

I believe the iPhone has an 8 digit memory address?

Comment: It's your choice. You have to define the scheme.

Comment: Hi Sulthan, so the memory access work is not built in? But rather requires extending the file system with a subclass?  This is above my head.  What I have in mind is fairly straightforward, but I'm not sure about the complexity of the subclassing.  Could someone who knows this stuff please contact me?

Comment: @user1393107 I believe you don't understand the difference between memory and filesystem. When you map a file into memory, you can't access it in the memory using that name. It's just a chunk of memory. You can then synchronize the memory into the file again but you can't address the memory using the file path - if you don't implement it yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to access the file completely via memory - read and write to memory.  Rather than to a file system.  So I can use such stuff as AV Foundation tools... via memory rather than file - to speed up latency.

Comment: I don't think AV performance is a problem because reading from /writing to file system. Usually these tools can work only with the filesystem, anyway.

Comment: @Alistair have you find a solution? I have the same problem, because of security reasons I'm not able to write camera recording to disk (I'm using AssetWriter) in plain format. Before saving to disk I need first to encrypt data, but not able to suppress saving into file. Saving in "virtual" file will solve it :) Thanks!